# MongoDB or store BSON as file?

Tags: json, mongodb, architecture, backend, system-design

I have special case where every JSON document stored and loaded in a whole. Thus, complex query is not required. This can be a reason to store every document in Object Storage as BSON instead of MongoDB. However, is there any drawbacks and considerations for that? Any performance and maintainability issues?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got your question correctly but MongoDB does store documents as a BSON(binary JSON) and if you want to just store JSON in MongoDB and retrieve it as a whole there won't be any performance issue.

Comment: Yes MongoDB can do that. The core question is any drawback of storing BSON as file instead of MongoDB regarding condition that I've explained before?

Comment: storing and retrieving files in the system can be slow. MongoDB has already done optimization over that. I would say do a benchmark and check.